# React Native - Firebase credentials in separate file

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

My goal is to have my firebase setup in a `firebase_setup.js` file in my `root` directory of my React Native project. I want to do this because it will allow me to perform `import firebaseApp from 'AppName/firebase_setup'` in my `login.js` and `signup.js` files.

I don't want to keep copying and pasting my Firebase credentials in every component I want to use the `firebaseApp` variable in.

**firebase_setup.js**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "FIREBASE_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  databaseURL: "FIREBASE_DB_URL",
  storageBucket: "",
};

export default const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

However, when I refresh the iPhone simulator I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: AppName/firebase_setup.js: Unexpected token (11:15)
```

It seems to have some issue with me using `export default` on `firebaseApp`. Any insight on this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the last line to:

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebaseApp;
```

[Why the syntax is invalid](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/why-is-export-default-var-a-1-invalid-syntax)

> Exporting a variable declaration list as "default" wouldn't make sense: for one, the list can have more than one element:

```
export default var a, b, c;  // Non-sensical
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked! I appreciate the explanation.